# copy file with google drive api v3 return "The provided file ID is not usable."

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

There a error when i try to copy file use google drive api. Is there a param that i lack?
this the error i get :

```
{
  "error":{
    "errors":[
      {
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"fileIdNotUsable",
        "message":"The provided file ID is not usable.",
        "locationType":"other",
        "location":"file.id"
      }
    ],
    "code":400,
    "message":"The provided file ID is not usable."
  }
}
```

This my code :

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET'));
    $client->refreshToken(env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN'));
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $optParams = array(
      'pageSize' => 10,
      'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
    );
    $files = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    foreach($files as $value){
      if($value->mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'){
        $service->files->copy($value->id, $value);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of file is it? Where is it located within the Drive ecosystem?

Comment: thanks for replied, i have solved my problem, i put the wrong params on copy method

Comment: not required, but don't you think you should share the answer?

Comment: The first argument to `copy()` is the ID of the file to copy. The second argument to `copy()` is used to describe what is desired of the resulting copy. Specifically, you'd want to set the file name of the second argument. At least from using their Go SDK, it appears you also need to unset the ID of the copy. E.g. `$copy = clone $value; $copy->name = $value->name . ' (copy)'; $copy->id = ''; $service->files->copy($value->id, $copy);`